# Creating variables from command line in BASH

Tags: c, bash

I'm a very new user to bash, so bear with me.
I'm trying to run a bash script that will take inputs from the command line, and then run a c program which its output to other c programs.
For example, at command line I would enter as follows:

```
$ ./script.sh -flag file1 < file2
```

The within the script I would have:

```
./c_program -flag file1 < file2 | other_c_program
```

The problem is, `-flag`, `file1` and `file2` need to be variable.
Now I know that for `-flag` and file this is fairly simple- I can do

```
FLAG=$1
FILE1=$2
./c_program $FLAG FILE1
```

My problem is: is there a way to assign a variable within the script to `file2`?

EDIT:
It's a requirement of the program that the script is called as
$ ./script.sh -flag file1 < file2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run `./c_program` exactly as you have it, and it will inherit stdin from the parent script. It will read from wherever its parent process is reading from.

```
FLAG=$1
FILE1=$2
./c_program "$FLAG" "$FILE1" | other_c_program    # `< file2' is implicit
```

Also, it's a good idea to quote variable expansions. That way if `$FILE1` contains whitespace or other tricky characters the script will still work.

Comment: Weird. First few time I did this I got a seg fault...then it started working fine. Thanks! Just need to iron out a few problems in my c code I guess

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do what you are asking.  This is because when you run this:

```
$ ./script.sh -flag file1 < file2
```

The shell which interprets the command will open `file2` for reading and pipe its contents to `script.sh`.  Your script will never know what the file's name was, therefore cannot store that name as a variable.  However, you could invoke your script this way:

```
$ ./script.sh -flag file1 file2
```

Then it is quite straightforward--you already know how to get `file1`, and `file2` is the same.

Comment: Is there some way I can pipe file2 from the script into ./c_program then? Unfortunately I have to have < file2.

Comment: Absolutely: just do nothing and c_program will read from stdin.  Do not do `< file2` within your script--just say `./c_program -flag file1 | other_c_program`.  This is what @JohnKugelman's answer says too.